# Are .NET automatic data forms a good idea?

Tags: .net, winforms, ado.net

I'm a Linux guy usually, but at the moment I'm trying to evaluate .NET for a Windows desktop application. All it needs to do is to display some forms that link to a database, let the user edit the data and then produce reports based on it. I found a walkthough at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171884.aspx that automatically produces forms based on the data structure, which seems very nice!

On the other hand, I am concerned that this might be just a demo to show to managers :-) I didn't find easy ways to extend upon the pre-made forms, even basic things such as concatenating the first and last names together so people can be selected from a list. 
So here are my questions:

1. Is this technology extensible enough to allow me to create different types of forms and other reasonable requirements which may pop up?
2. Will I ever have to touch the massive amount of generated code that it makes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about the procedure outlinked in the link you provided.  The wizards just mimic what a regular programmer would do by hand.

> Is this technology extensible enough
>   to allow me to create different types
>   of forms and other reasonable
>   requirements which may pop up?

Check out T4 templates: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/05/01/visual-studios-t4-code-generation.aspx

> Will I ever have to touch the massive
>   amount of generated code that it
>   makes?

Only if you want to customize the output (which is usually).